# php secure info issues

Tags: php, security

hi i am running php secure info and i am getting the following issues.

```
Warning
allow_url_fopen is enabled. This could be a serious security risk. You should disable allow_url_fopen and consider using the PHP cURL functions instead.
Current Value:  1
Recommended Value:  0
```

Can someone explain how i can fix this.

```
Warning
PHP may be executing as a "privileged" group, which could be a serious security vulnerability.
Current Value:  99
Recommended Value:  100

Warning
PHP may be executing as a "privileged" user, which could be a serious security vulnerability.
Current Value:  99
Recommended Value:  100
```

Comment: Are you running apache as root?

Comment: @alfabravo: root is UID 0;. The last part clearly states it's UID 99. Probably www-data or similar.

Comment: [First hit on "allow_url_fopen is enabled"](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=263572.0). ;-)

Comment: whats been happening is my site has been hacked over and over again keep finding this in index.php <script language="javascript" src="http://adfusionnetwork.com/?campaignid=135324812&type=tracking"></script> i delete it reappears ????

Answer (score 2):

I love when people take time to secure your PHP setup; so props to you!

Yes, you should turn allow_url_fopen off because this opens you up to many security issues as far as executing remote scripts. You can do that by editing you php.ini file; usually located in /etc/php.ini, but just to make sure check your phpinfo() and see where it says "Loaded Configuration File". Once you've found it, change the following value:

```
allow_url_fopen = 0
```

As far as PHP executing as a "priveleged" group, you will need to check what group your apache user is associated with. You can do this via command-line if you have shell access:

```
id {username}
```

where {username} is the name of your apache user ... could be "apache" could be "php" could be "www-data", etc. It's recommended that the apache user is in its own user group:

```
apache.apache
```

To do this, you can use the following command:

```
useradd -G {group-name} username
```

so it would look like:

```
useradd -G apache apache
```

Comment: great; let me know if you have any questions. If its helpful to you, then an upvote would be nice :)

Comment: So - I've had sleepless nights for the last 2 months (no exaggeration!) trying to work out why some of the sites hosted on my VPS are being repeatedly infected with Remote Access Trojans. After finally coming across this, I think I may have finally found the answer. Here's hoping it will stop when I change this setting to 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first message means just what it says, allow_url_fopen is enabled in your php.ini, which allows fopen-based functions to open URL's, for example this would work:

```
fopen('http://www.example.com/somefile.txt');
```

Malicous users could use this to load their remote files to your webserver.

The second block of messages means that you're running the PHP interpreter (and most likely that is through your web server like Apache or nginx) as a "priviliged" user, which is in most cases the `root` user. And that is a very bad idea, since this user has unlimited system access, which you are then passing along to your web server. That would make any security vulnerability in your web server give any intruder complete root access.

So it comes down to doing 2 things if you want these messages to be fixed:

1. Set allow_url_fopen in your php.ini to 0.
2. Make sure that you don't start your web browser as the root user, but rather a user like www-data or apache (present on most systems where Apache is installed through the package manager).